# How to stop a scheduled notification

Tags: firebase, push-notification

I have scheduled a notification on the Firebase console using cloud messaging. The notification has been created yesterday and was scheduled for today and now I can't find a way to delete or change the text. The status says "In progress". How can I delete or change the notification?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?